# simplifying this basic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I don't quite get how to simplify this equation correctly. Could someone show me the steps please? Big thanks!

So if...

$$f(x) = x^3$$

then:

$$f(x+\Delta x) = (x+\Delta x)^3$$

and can be simplified to:

$$(x+\Delta x)^3  = x^3 + 3x^2 \Delta x + 3x (\Delta x)^2 + (\Delta x)^3$$

I never seem to end up with the correct number of $\Delta x$'s though when I do this myself :(

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I took the liberty to typeset your formulas using MathJax (LaTeX) for better readability. When you edit your posts or type in new questions, you will see useful links which explain how to use MathJax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try multiplying it like this:
$$
(x+y)^3=(x+y)(x+y)^2=(x+y)(x^2+2xy+y^2).
$$
(where $y=\Delta x$)

Comment: Thanks for the formatting TZakrevskiy.

Comment: Changing to y helps, but I don't get where the 2xy is coming from.

Comment: It's coming from multiplying. Do you know how to FOIL?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I looked up foil and got the end result.